# source .sh file for vscode launch

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have a .sh file which sets several environment variables which I need for a software to run. I am trying to debug that software with vscode, and I need to source that file so the debugger can start the software.

I can't source the file and then launch vscode, as the software is running inside a docker container, and the envvars point to locations inside the docker container.

I would like to know if there is a way to source the .sh file as part of the launch.json configuration.

Comment: use the `env` command? (if you're not on windows) what platforms do you need to support?

Comment: I am just using linux. I dont understand how `env` command can help me here